# How can connect mysql to spring roo?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-roo, roo

Spring-roo can't be connect to MySQL
when i execute command database reverse engineer --schema test --package  then it give error:

> Could not initialize class com.mysql.jdbc.Connection...

Image of error:

[image]

Comment: post your code snippet

Comment: Please show your config, especially the database connection configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 things:

1. Configure connection info in project in *src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/database.properties* file. Spring Roo uses it to connect DB.
2. Make JDBC driver accessible by Spring Roo installing it in OSGi environ ( see [manual section about it](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/base-dbre.html#dbre_installation) )

Good luck!